# How to make a Flyout Box using C++?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I am working with metro and I am trying to make a flyout window. I have found a class called CoreWindowFlyout, but it cannot be used for creating flyouts with other controls than buttons.

Does someone know how to do this in C++?

Comment: I suggest adding the C++/CX tag.  winrt is likely enough to get attention, but might as well use the tags that we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XAML in combination with your C++ application you'll want to look at using the `Popup` class.  In the developer preview the "light dismiss" capability isn't built-in so you will have to manage that on your own, but it will eventually have light dismiss capabilities, so using that will get you along the right path.